# how to uncycle and change column ratio with jeet

Tags: stylus, jeet-grid

I am trying to break from 4 columns to 3 by uncycling,
the initial ratio looks like this

```
col(1/4, gutter: .5, cycle: 4)
```

then i try changing it at laptop resolution to only 3 columns

```
uncycle()
col(1/3, gutter: .5, cycle: 3)
```

is there any way to change ratios like this?

Answer (score 0):

According to their `column` API, I think you should use

```
col(1/3, gutter: .5, uncycle:4, cycle: 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, the correct way to do this is:

```
@include col(1/3, $uncycle:4, $cycle:3);
```

So basically you first uncycle the number of previous cycles, and after that you enter the new number of cycles.

For more information, check the Jeet documentation. http://jeet.gs